# CentOs Boot Errors

Tags: centos, vps

I am trying to install CentOs 6.7 on a VPS. I downloaded the LiveCD iso from CentOs's website and put it on a bootable thumb drive, and even burned it to CD, however when booting from either sources, I get this error.

[image: CentOs 6.7 boot error]

I have even re-download the same file from different source links but the same thing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use second newest kernel.
i.e: 
During a startup, press ESC to stop the boot
login and remove the kernel you are using. download the newest kernel then restart